# Netty server can't get all the messages that client sent

Tags: netty

I have a netty server and client in the project and want to exchange message between them.

The netty server code:

```
//主事件池
private EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

//副事件池
private EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

//服务端通道
private Channel serverChannel;

/**
 * 绑定本机监听
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void Start(int port) throws Exception {

    //启动器
    ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    //为Acceptor设置事件池，为客户端接收设置事件池
    serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            //工厂模式，创建NioServerSocketChannel类对象
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            //等待队列大小
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
            //地址复用
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            //日志记录组件的level
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            //各种业务处理handler
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    //编码器
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageDecoder", new MicroMessageDecoder(1024, 4, 4));
                    //解码器
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageEncoder", new MicroMessageEncoder());
                    //业务处理handler
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyHandler", new MicroServerHandler());
                }
            });

    //绑定本机
    String host = "127.0.0.1";

    //绑定端口，同步等待成功
    ChannelFuture future = serverBootstrap.bind(host, port).sync();

    //注册连接事件监听器
    future.addListener(cfl -> {
        if (cfl.isSuccess()) {
            logger.info("服务端[" + host + ":" + port + "]已上线...");
            serverChannel = future.channel();
        }
    });

    //注册关闭事件监听器
    future.channel().closeFuture().addListener(cfl -> {
        //关闭服务端
        close();
        logger.info("服务端[" + host + ":" + port + "]已下线...");
    });
}

/**
 * 关闭server
 */
public void close() {
    //关闭套接字
    if(serverChannel!=null){
        serverChannel.close();
    }
    //关闭主线程组
    if (bossGroup != null) {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
    //关闭副线程组
    if (workerGroup != null) {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

The netty client code:

```
  @Service
  public class MicroClient {

//日志记录
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroClient.class);

//事件池
private EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

//启动器
private Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

//客户端通道
private Channel clientChannel;

//客户端处理handler
private MicroClientHandler microClientHandler;

/**
 * 连接服务器
 * @param host
 * @param port
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void Connect(String host, int port) throws InterruptedException {
    microClientHandler = new MicroClientHandler();
    bootstrap.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    //解码器
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageDecoder", new MicroMessageDecoder(1024, 4, 4));
                    //编码器
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageEncoder", new MicroMessageEncoder());
                    //业务处理
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("clientHandler", microClientHandler);
                }
            });

    //发起同步连接操作
    ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync();

    //检测连接完毕
    if(channelFuture.isDone()){
        logger.info("客户端[" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress().toString() + "]已连接...");
        clientChannel = channelFuture.channel();
    }

    //注册关闭事件
    channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().addListener(cfl -> {
        close();
        logger.info("客户端[" + channelFuture.channel().localAddress().toString() + "]已断开...");
    });
}

/**
 * 客户端关闭
 */
private void close() {
    //关闭客户端套接字
    if(clientChannel!=null){
        clientChannel.close();
    }
    //关闭客户端线程组
    if (group != null) {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

/**
 * 客户端发送信息
 * @param microMessage
 */
public void send( MicroMessage microMessage) {
    microClientHandler.send(microMessage);
}

}
```

The Server handler code :

```
public class MicroServerHandler  extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroServerHandler.class);

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    MicroMessage message = (MicroMessage) msg;
    logger.error("receive client message : " + message.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    ctx.fireExceptionCaught(cause);
    ctx.close();
}

}
```

The Client handler code :

```
public class MicroClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroClientHandler.class);

private ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String message = "message timestamp " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + i;
        MicroMessage microMessage = new MicroMessage();
        microMessage.setMessage(message);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(microMessage);
        System.out.println("send client message : " + message);
    }
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    MicroMessage message = (MicroMessage) msg;
}

public void send(MicroMessage microMessage) {
    if (ctx != null) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(microMessage);
    }else{
        logger.error("ctx is not prepared well now...");
    }
}
}
```

The MessageDecoder code:

```
public class MicroMessageDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder{

public MicroMessageDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength) {
    super(maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength);
}

@Override
public  Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    try {
        byte[] dstBytes = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        in.readBytes(dstBytes, 0, in.readableBytes());
        MicroMessage microMessage = MicroSerializeUtil.deserialize(dstBytes, MicroMessage.class);
        return microMessage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception when decoding: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The messageEncoder code:

```
public class MicroMessageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<MicroMessage> {

@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MicroMessage msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
    out.writeBytes(MicroSerializeUtil.serialize(msg));
}
}
```

The SerializeUtil code, I used the protostuff as my codec stuff:

```
public class MicroSerializeUtil {

private static class SerializeData{
    private Object target;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static byte[] serialize(Object object) {
    SerializeData serializeData = new SerializeData();
    serializeData.target = object;
    Class<SerializeData> serializeDataClass = (Class<SerializeData>) serializeData.getClass();
    LinkedBuffer linkedBuffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate(1024 * 4);
    try {
        Schema<SerializeData> schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(serializeDataClass);
        return ProtobufIOUtil.toByteArray(serializeData, schema, linkedBuffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        linkedBuffer.clear();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T deserialize(byte[] data, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        Schema<SerializeData> schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(SerializeData.class);
        SerializeData serializeData = schema.newMessage();
        ProtobufIOUtil.mergeFrom(data, serializeData, schema);
        return (T) serializeData.target;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}
```

The server test as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring-config.xml"})
public class ServerTest {

@Resource
private MicroServer microServer;

@Test
public void testServer() throws Exception {
    microServer.Start(9023);
    System.in.read();
}
}
```

The client test as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring-config.xml"})
public class ClientTest {

@Resource
private MicroClient microClient;

@Before
public void init() throws InterruptedException {
    microClient.Connect("127.0.0.1",9023);
}

@Test
public void testClient() throws Exception {
    System.in.read();
}
}
```

The server output below:

```
2020-06-10 17:21:54,970 INFO  [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] micro.MicroServer (MicroServer.java:82) - 服务端[127.0.0.1:9023]已上线...
2020-06-10 17:22:00,232 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] micro.MicroServerHandler (MicroServerHandler.java:21) - receive client message : message timestamp 1591780920120 9
```

The client output below:

```
2020-06-10 17:21:59,988 INFO  [main] micro.MicroClient (MicroClient.java:67) - 客户端[/127.0.0.1:49299]已连接...
send client message : message timestamp 1591780919987 0
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920117 1
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920117 2
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920118 3
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920118 4
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920118 5
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920119 6
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920119 7
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920119 8
send client message : message timestamp 1591780920120 9
```

So from the output of the log, we can see that, client side sends 10 message to server side, but the server side only receives one message.
Anything wrong for my code? I think maybe protostuff that I mis-used?

EDIT:
in MicroMessageDecoder class, I debugged the dstBytes variable and got below info :

```
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477591 0
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 1
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 2
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 3
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 4
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 5
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 6
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 7
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 8
P�*com.tw.components.micro.codec.MicroMessage
!message timestamp 1591783477598 9
```

All messages here, So maybe the decoder works wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `ChannelFuture` that is returned by `writeAndFlush` to be understand if the write failed.

For doing so add a `ChannelFutureListener` to it:

```
channel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {


    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            ...
        } else {
            Throwable cause = future.cause();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: checked this, all messages sent ok. 
Now I can see that all messages are in message decoder, but output only one message, the reason lied in the decoder.

Comment: sorry, I means I add the listener and can see that all the messages the client sent are all success, no messages that fail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this solved. Becuase that 10 messages sent by client are posted to server side in a time , so we need to add LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to split the messages.

```
public class MicroLengthDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {
public MicroLengthDecoder(int maxFrameLength, int lengthFieldOffset, int lengthFieldLength) {
    super(maxFrameLength, lengthFieldOffset, lengthFieldLength);
    }
}
```

Then add it as below:

```
.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    //拆分消息，头部字节长度为4字节
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyLengthDecoder", new MicroLengthDecoder(1024 * 1024, 0, 4));
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageEncoder", new MicroMessageEncoder());
                    channel.pipeline().addLast("nettyMessageDecoder", new MicroMessageDecoder());
                   ....
                }
            });
```

need to change below two classes:

```
public class MicroMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> obj) throws Exception {
    try {
        byte[] originBytes = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        in.readBytes(originBytes, 0, in.readableBytes());

        //去掉头部的4字节
        byte[] dstBytes = new byte[originBytes.length-4];
        System.arraycopy(originBytes,4,dstBytes,0,dstBytes.length);

        MicroMessage microMessage = MicroSerializeUtil.deserialize(dstBytes, MicroMessage.class);
        obj.add(microMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception when decoding: " + e);
    }
}
}


public class MicroMessageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<MicroMessage> {

@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MicroMessage msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = MicroSerializeUtil.serialize(msg);
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(intToBytes(data.length), data);
    out.writeBytes(buf);
}

/**
 * 在消息体头部附带4字节，主要是为了拆分消息用
 * @param num
 * @return
 */
public byte[] intToBytes(int num) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (num >> (24 - i * 8));
    }
    return bytes;
}
}
```